# Jquery.validate() not "reloading" after form submission (meteor.js)

Tags: jquery, validation, meteor, jquery-validate

I have a form with Jquery.validate() rules attached.  This is all working fine, and the validation rules are being applied fine on first page load.

After a user submits the form, I show them a "thank you" message, which shows up using a reactiveVar based on the submission.  After ~10 seconds, I change the reactiveVar, remove the thank you, and show them the form again.

If a user tries to fill out the form now, the validation rules do not apply (on page refresh they work again fine, but I don't want to have to refresh the page).  What is going on?

```
Template.inquiry.onCreated( function() {
    //toggles 'thank you' on inquiry template
    this.showForm = new ReactiveVar( true );
});

Template.inquiry.onRendered(function(){
    $('#request-form').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 255
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                emailUnique: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 255
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Please let us know your name."
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter an email address so we can reach you.",
                email: "You've entered an invalid email address.",
                minlength: "Your email must be at least {0} characters.",
                emailUnique: "That email has already been submitted.  Please enter a unique email!"
            },
        }
    });
});


<template name="inquiry">

{{#if showForm }} 

form here

{{else}} 

Thank you here

{{/if}} 


Template.inquiry.events({
        'submit form': function(event, template) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form = template.$('#request-form');

                if ($form.valid()) {

                    var name = event.target.name.value;
                    var email = event.target.email.value;

                    UserList.insert({
                        name: name,
                        email: email,
                    });

                    template.showForm.set( false );

                    Meteor.setTimeout( function() {
                      template.showForm.set( true );
                    }, 10000); // Reset after 10 seconds.
                }

            window.scroll(0,0);  
        }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to reset the form?  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.resetForm/

Comment: I tried adding:  $('#request-form').validate().resetForm(); after the timeout, and it still is giving me the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because of your if/else in your template.  When the thank-you form shows, it completely removes your other form from your document.  When it comes back up, .validate() doesn't rerun. You should only hide the form instead of completely removing it from the DOM.

Code:

```
<template name="inquiry">

    <form id="request-form" style="{{#unless showForm}}visibility:hidden;{{/unless}}">
      ...
    </form>

    {{#unless showForm}} 

      Thank you form here

    {{/unless}} 

</template>
```

Comment: How would I implement #2?

Comment: You cannot run `.validate()` multiple times on the same page.  It's only used once to initialize the plugin on page load.

Comment: Interesting.  You'll have to go with option #1 then.

Comment: sorry, but how would I just hide the form?  can I still use the reactive var?

Comment: You'll have to add another helper, but that helper can just return a CSS class that would either make the form visible or not based on the reactive var value.

Comment: Changed my answer to reflect the first option only.  I did it using your existing helper and using an inline CSS style instead of a class.